# html5 canvas switch draw functions

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

For a project I'm working on I need to draw a solar system on the canvas using the arc function and the lineTo function,and with one button press switch between them. I think I'm close I can switch once but I can't switch back to the original. Sorry for the massive block of code but I've been working on this for hours and I can no longer remember what is important.

```
    if (window.addEventListener) 
{
    window.addEventListener( 'load', initialise, false);
    window.addEventListener('keydown',onKeyDown, false);
}

var canvas;
var context;
var angle = 0;
var time = 20;
var paused = false;
var timer;
var drawStyle = drawArc();

function onKeyDown(event) 
{ 
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode)
    { 
        case 80: //p
        togglePause();
        break; 
    }
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case 75: //k
        toggleDrawStyle();
        break; 
    }
        switch(keyCode)
    {
        case 70: //f
        speedUp();
        break; 
    }
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case 82: //r
        speedDown();
        break; 
    }
}

function toggleDrawStyle()
{
    if(drawStyle == drawArc())
    {
        drawStyle = drawLine();
    }
    else if(drawStyle == drawLine())
    {
        drawStyle = drawArc();
    }
}

function speedUp()
{
    time = time / 2;
}

function speedDown()
{
        time = time * 2;
}

function togglePause() 
{
    if (!paused)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        paused = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        timer = setInterval(drawArc, time);
        timer = setInterval(drawLine, time);
        paused = false;
    }
}


function initialise() 
{
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 

    if (!canvas.getContext)
    { 
        alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!'); 
        return; 
    }

    context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    if (!context)
    { 
        alert('Error: failed to getContext!'); 
        return; 
    }

    timer = setInterval(drawArc, time);

}

function drawArc() 
{ 
    clearCanvas();
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    incrementAngle();
    context.save();
    //draw the sun
    context.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
    circle(0, 0, 30, "#ffaa00");

    //draw mercury
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*1.5);
    moveCirlce(1/6, 1/6 , 30 , 30, "#555555");
    context.restore();

    //draw venus
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*1.25);
    moveCirlce(1/5, 1/5, 40, 40, "#aa0011");
    context.restore();

    // draw earth
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
    moveCirlce(0.3, 0.3, 55, 55, "#0077ff");
    context.restore();

    //draw the moon
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
    context.translate(55, 55);
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle) * 2);
    moveCirlce(1/15, 1/15, 10, 10, "#555555");
    context.restore();

    //draw mars
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle) *0.9);
    moveCirlce(1/3, 1/3, 80, 80, "#ff0000");
    context.restore();

    //draw jupiter
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)* 0.75);
    moveCirlce(2/3, 2/3, 110, 110, "#cc8811");
    context.restore();

    //draw sautrn
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*0.55);
    moveCirlce(17/30, 17/30, 140, 140, "#dd7722");
    context.restore();

    //draw uranus
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*0.3);
    moveCirlce(14/30, 14/30, 170, 170, "#4444ff");
    context.restore();

    //draw neptune
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*0.2);
    moveCirlce(11/30, 11/30, 190, 190, "#9999ff");
    context.restore();
    context.restore();


}

function drawLine()
{
    clearCanvas();
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    incrementAngle();
    context.save();
    //draw sun
    context.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
    lineCircle(0, 0, 30, "#ffaa00");    

    //draw mercury
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*1.5);
    moveLineCirlce(1/6, 1/6 , 30 , 30, "#555555");
    context.restore();

    //draw venus
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*1.25);
    moveLineCirlce(1/5, 1/5, 40, 40, "#aa0011");
    context.restore();

    // draw earth
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
    moveLineCirlce(0.3, 0.3, 55, 55, "#0077ff");
    context.restore();

    //draw the moon
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle));
    context.translate(55, 55);
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle) * 2);
    moveLineCirlce(1/15, 1/15, 10, 10, "#555555");
    context.restore();

    //draw mars
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle) *0.9);
    moveLineCirlce(1/3, 1/3, 80, 80, "#ff0000");
    context.restore();

    //draw jupiter
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)* 0.75);
    moveLineCirlce(2/3, 2/3, 110, 110, "#cc8811");
    context.restore();

    //draw sautrn
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*0.55);
    moveLineCirlce(17/30, 17/30, 140, 140, "#dd7722");
    context.restore();

    //draw uranus
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*0.3);
    moveLineCirlce(14/30, 14/30, 170, 170, "#4444ff");
    context.restore();

    //draw neptune
    context.save();
    context.rotate(convertToRadians(angle)*0.2);
    moveLineCirlce(11/30, 11/30, 190, 190, "#9999ff");
    context.restore();
    context.restore();
}

function convertToRadians(degree) 
{
    return degree*(Math.PI/180);
}

function incrementAngle() 
{
    angle++;
}

function clearCanvas()
{
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
}
function circle(x, y, r , col)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = col;
    context.fill();
}

function moveCirlce(a, b, x, y, col)
{
    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.scale(a, b);
    circle(0, 0, 30, col);
    context.restore();
}

function lineCircle(a, b, r, col)
{
    var theta = Math.PI * 2 / 9;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i = i + 1) 
    {
        var angle = theta * i;
        var x = a + r * Math.cos(angle);
        var y = b + r * Math.sin(angle);
        if (i == 0) 
        {
            context.moveTo(x,y);
        }
        else 
        {
            context.lineTo(x,y);
        }
    }
    context.fillStyle = col;
    context.fill();
}

function moveLineCirlce(a, b, x, y, col)
{
    context.save();
    context.translate(x, y);
    context.scale(a, b);
    lineCircle(0, 0, 30, col);
    context.restore();
}

initialise();
drawArc();
```

Comment: Haha, that's why it's a good idea to use meaningful names and comment sections of code, specifying the relevance and use.

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statements, as written, are nothing more than a bizarre way to write a bunch of `if (condition) do_statements;`  so that's not the problem (although it *does* mean you aren't using a switch statement as intended; if this is homework for a grade, this might mean some deductions).

A clear indication that something is a muck is that your `togglePause` fires `setInterval` with  `drawArc` and  then overwrites the timer id by also firing `setInterval` with  `drawLine`.  This means whenever you attempt to clearInterval, you're only clearing the interval for `drawLine`.

You also have a `drawStyle` variable, but you aren't really using it for anything, as drawArc and drawLine don't return any values.

So, some hints...

- Assign something proper to your drawStyle variable... whether or not you use some flag or the actual functions themselves, I don't care.
- handle your setInterval logic better.  Hint:  with a few tweaks, you could use just use `timer = setInterval(function(){drawStyle();}, time);` everywhere.
- your speed up/slow down functionality is broken.  your solar system should work by varying time increments--that is, instead of just incrementing angle by 1, increment it by some variable amount that you can vary.
- Finally, after you get the logic worked out, [Fix your switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)